# Is the process of backing-up a database and sending the generated CSV to a remote server easier on Windows or Linux?

Tags: linux, windows

My employers currently use a Windows IIS Database server which I am trying to change to Linux.

But I need to convince them.

**There is a requirement to automate a process of backing-up the database and sending the generated CSV to a remote server.**
Can anyone tell me if the process described above is easier to accomplish on Windows or Linux?

Also, **is there a Linux based database system which can handle large volumes of data like Windows SQL SERVER ?**

Comment: I prefer Linux to Windows, but for this requirement it makes absolutely **no difference**.  I don't even have to know which operating system the database is running on.  A good database system will abstract that away.

Answer (score 1):

Automation of backup: the easiness of the solution depends on which system do you know better. Basically it is not that much of a difference between writing a batch file and putting in windows task manager or writing a bash script and putting it in cron.

SQL Server: MySQL (maybe with clustering) or Oracle (commercial) should do it.